# makeinitramfs and grub-update for compiled Ubuntu Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel

I'm modifying the Ubuntu Kernel and I've noticed: Whenever I install Kernel updates from the main repos initramfs and grub are updated automatically. However, in compiled kernels these steps are completed outside of the install of the newly created kernel.

I'm loosely following the directions from: [Ubuntu KerenelTeam Wiki: Git Kernel Building](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild#Using_Ubuntu_Kernel_Configuration)

How can I produce the same effect for my version of the kernel packages? Would this require a third package that depends on the image/header produced which then runs the final setup scripts?

Comment: Have you user `kernel-package` to build the kernel?

Comment: Can you show the exact `make-kpkg` command line you're using, and the output you obtain during installation of the generated package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using what is documented in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile instead of the `make-kpkg` way. This way you'll actually build the package exactly the same way it is built in the archive.